# How to calculate exponential growth when the value is a percentage or probability?

Tags: probability, percentage, function, growth-model

I have a variable `x` that takes values between 1 and 0 (`0<x<1`). I want to calculate value of `x` at period `t` with growth value `g` using exponential growth function (`x*(1+g)^t`). However, as `t` becomes larger, `x` becomes bigger than 1.

I've tried to overcome this by using `log(x)` with the following function:
`exp(log(x)*(1-g)^t)` . This partly solves the issue of inflating beyond 1 but i cannot interpret what g does at this context. Is there any exponential growth formula for percentage or probability values?

Comment: you cant get all that you want, e.g. exponential growth of an upper bounded variable, but if you try sometimes you can get what you need. think of what you really need

Comment: Is there any other growth function that i can apply to probability/percentage values?

Comment: sigmoid is a growth function, and it can be exponential in the middle

Comment: That was exactly what i needed. Thank you very much. If you want, you can submit your comment as an answer and i can verify it.